# Catastrophic backtracking on regular expression

Tags: regex, expression

necesito su ayuda, tengo una expresion regular que funciona bien en la mayoria de los casos

La regex es `/^\s*?ingress:\d?(?:[\r\n\s]|.)*?^.*host:\s(.*)/gmi`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es extraer el valor de host: parandome la busqueda desde el primer tag que quiera, hasta el segundo tag

Esto funciona bien, pero el problema es cuando alguno de los archivos no contienen la palabra "host:", en este escenario el proyecto de NodeJs se queda bloqueado en el analisis de la expresion regular, y cuando fui a regex101 para analizar el error veo que teng oun error en la web

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no logro entender cual es el problema en la expresion regular que causa esto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto tiene que ver con una característica propia de la interpretación de las expresiones regulares, el *backtracking*. Básicamente el análisis contempla los caminos -multiversos- diferentes disponibles al interpretar una expresión que sea ambigua dada una entrada. Si algo falla, el análisis se regresa un paso y revisa cuál de todos esos casos en los que un paso anterior fue exitoso, permite que el paso posterior también sea exitoso.
Tener cuantificadores anidados suele causar ésto.

¿Enredado? Bueno, es parte de la magia oscura de las expresiones regulares.

En tu caso, te está diciendo que, cuando falla el anáilsis en el segmento que debería contener `host:` (porque no está), esa expresión tiene múltiples formas de hacer match con el contenido previo; posiblemente el fragmento `\d?(?:[\r\n\s]|.)*?^` es el culpable. Así pues, una expresión ambigua dado el input puede terminar tardando muchísimo tiempo al tener muchas posibles opciones para validar, ir y volver muchas veces hasta confirmar que en ningún multiverso <strike>muere Thanos</strike> la expresión hace match. Y eso ES catastrófico a ojos del motor JS en tu navegador.

En una prueba rápida, [probé](https://regexr.com/6prse) cambiando tu expresión a:

```
^\s*?ingress:\d?([\w\s\":]*)?^\s*host:\s*(.*)$/gmi
```

Y pareciera funcionar. Usamos el `^` para indicar que la línea de host comienza ahí, y el análisis de lo que va entre ingress y host es esencialmente cualquier cosa que no viene al caso.

Habría que ver si cubre los casos en tu archivo origen y el trabajo no da espera, pero esta es la explicación de por qué pasa eso (y por qué en producción, la terminal que corra eso con un archivo más grande estallaría en llamas o consumiría mucho tiempo y recursos)

[Explicación detallada y ejemplos en inglés](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)